# build & deploy failure

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, nunjucks, cicd

We are using `Nunjucks` and `GitLab` to create and deploy our project website.

Up until a week ago, there were no problems, but suddenly we noticed that the changes to the website would not take effect after building and deploying.

Once we modify something, we run `npm run gulp all` and if there are no errors, we open the webpages from within the `dist` folder to see if it all looks fine. If we are happy, we commit and push, which automatically triggers the `GitLab` CI/CD job and after a few minutes, the live website shows the changes.

Here is the code in our `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
before_script:
  ##
  ## Run ssh-agent inside the build environment.
  ##
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

  ##
  ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store.
  ##
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add - > /dev/null

  ##
  ## Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions.
  ##
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh

  ##
  ## Add Host Keys.
  ##
  - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

stages: 
  - build
  - deploy

prod_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Build"
    - npm install --loglevel verbose
    - npm install natives@1.1.6
    - npm run gulp all
    - ls
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - Sisyphus
  
prod_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to webserver"
    - npm install --loglevel verbose
    - npm install natives@1.1.6
    - npm run gulp all
    - rsync -av dist/ blah@blahblah.com:/var/www/blah/ --delete
  allow_failure: false
  environment:
    name: deploy
  only:
  - master
  tags:
    - Sisyphus
  when: always
```

The above content has not changes. It all used to be fine. So, we have no clue why recently the process does not update the website.

This is the content of our `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp') ;
var watch = require('gulp-watch') ;
var nunjucksRender = require('gulp-nunjucks-render');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var revRewrite = require('gulp-rev-rewrite');
var gulpClean = require('gulp-clean');

function clean() {
  return gulp.src('dist', { read: false, allowEmpty: true })
  // Renders template with nunjucks.
  .pipe( gulpClean() )
}

function renderNunjucks() {
  // Gets .html and .nunjucks files in pages.
  return gulp.src('pages/**/*.+(html|njk)')
  // Renders template with nunjucks.
  .pipe(nunjucksRender({
      path: ['templates', 'pages']
    }))
  // Outputs files in app folder.
  .pipe( gulp.dest('dist') )
}

function copyStatic() {
    return gulp.src('public/**/*')
  .pipe( rev() )
  .pipe( gulp.dest('dist') )
  .pipe( rev.manifest() )
  .pipe( gulp.dest('dist') );
}

function RevRewrite() {
  const manifest = gulp.src('dist/rev-manifest.json');
  return gulp.src('dist/**/*')
  .pipe( revRewrite({ manifest }) )
  .pipe( gulp.dest('dist') );
}

gulp.task('clean', clean);
gulp.task('nunjucks', gulp.series('clean', renderNunjucks))
gulp.task('copy', gulp.series('clean', copyStatic));
gulp.task('rev-rewrite', gulp.series('nunjucks', RevRewrite));
gulp.task('all', gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(copyStatic, renderNunjucks), RevRewrite));
```

Of course we have looked at the `Jobs` log files to see if there are any errors or red flags, but all seems to be OK, ending with a `Job succeeded` message.

What could possibly be the reason? We suspect some kind of failure to do proper cleanup, as sometimes we compare the `dist` and live website's pages (via inspecting them) and realize that, for example, the `index.css` file is empty, whereas it should contain the css stuff that we have put in it.

How do we find out if this is an update that broke the process or `rsync` not syncing and cleaning up, etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `checksum` to the end of your `rsync` command:

```
rsync -av dist/ blah@blahblah.com:/var/www/blah/ --delete --checksum
```

If the size and/or date of your file(s) are not changed for some reason, this usually happens...